# Picking 'linux-signed' as source package instead of 'linux-image-4.15.0-23-generic'

Tags: package-management, software-installation, kernel, software-sources

I added

```
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
```

into my `sources.list`, did `apt update`

Here's what I'm getting:

```
vm@vm-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996:~$ apt-get source linux-image-4.15.0-23-generic 
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'linux-signed' as source package instead of 'linux-image-4.15.0-23-generic'
Need to get 17,8 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main linux-signed 4.15.0-23.25 (dsc) [2.050 B]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main linux-signed 4.15.0-23.25 (tar) [15,8 kB]
Fetched 17,8 kB in 1s (11,9 kB/s)       
dpkg-source: info: extracting linux-signed in linux-signed-4.15.0
dpkg-source: info: unpacking linux-signed_4.15.0-23.25.tar.xz
```

it keeps downloading `linux-signed`

**UPDATE:**

If I do

```
apt-get source linux
```

it works but then I still need to do

```
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

in order to install the dependencies. However, it will install the dependencies of `linux-signed`. If I try `sudo apt-get build-dep linux` it installs a lot of things that are not necessary to build a kernel